# Can the zeros of a non-zero differentiable function have a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that the set $A=\{x:f(x)=0\}$ has a limit point in $\mathbb R$ .

Does it imply that $f(x)\equiv 0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(1/x) &  x \neq 0 \\
0  & x = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
See what the function looks like [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[x%5E2%20*%20sin%281%2Fx%29%2C%7Bx%2C-0.1%2C0.1%7D]). Note that you can generalize, replace by $2$ by $n$ (i.e. $x^n \sin(1/x)$) and you have a $(n-1)$-times differentiable function and the set $A$ still has a limit point at $0$.

Note that you cannot hope for $f$ to be analytic, since non-zero analytic functions have isolated zeros. I don't know about smooth though.

Hope that helps,

Comment: yes you answered all my queries at one go;+1

Comment: @learnmore : the point is that this is a totally different picture compared to algebraic geometry, where the set of points where a section has a zero stalk is always open, hence in the case of varieties, dense. In real analysis functions are much more flexible and can wave like the way you saw. In complex analysis functions are somewhere in between ; the functions are not polynomials (e.g. they can be holomorphic such as $e^z$), but still they have some rigidity structure (bounded entire functions are constant). In many areas of mathematics this is a very important analogy to understand.

Comment: one quick question;can a real differentiable function have uncountable number of zeros

Comment: I assume you mean uncountable in the sense "not identically zero on any interval". That is a good question, I'll try thinking a bit.

Comment: you got it right ;would love to get back to you in future

Comment: I seriously don't understand downvotes sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\geq 0$.

The set of values where the function is $0$ is $(-\infty,0]$ which has limit points $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I think the intuition of the OP was in the case where the set of zeros is not closed.

Comment: I see, well, this won't hurt. Of course this answer can be easily modified to yield a non-closed example. I think what makes your answer more "special" is that the set of zeroes has empty interior

Comment: yes, but that's the intuition that the OP had that I wanted to destroy! :D

Comment: But the set of zeroes of any continuous function is closed!  It's the preimage of a closed set, after all.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad,

Comment: Can a differentiable real function have a bounded uncountable set of zeros without being a constant on any interval of positive length?  Note that  if we replace "differentiable" with "continuous" the answer is "yes".

Comment: what would be an example with continuous?

Comment: @dREaM : I guess I didn't make myself quite clear since what I said was wrong (about the closure thing) ; if $A'$ (resp. $\overline A$) denotes the set of limit points (resp. the closure) of $A$, instead of saying closed, I meant that $A = A' = \overline A$, e.g. all points are limit points (does this property have a name or a nice compact words-only reformulation that I want?). My example is different in that $A'$ is a point and $A = \overline A$ is countable.